# Updating solr on a ColdFusion 9 install?

Tags: coldfusion, solr

I'm thinking about upgrading the solr install included with ColdFusion 9 to the latest Apache release. This raises a few questions:

- Is there a compelling reason *not* to upgrade to 3.6 (is it slower than, more cumbersome than, or backwards-incompatible with 1.4) altogether?
- The solr install included with CF9 is customized. Is there a way to customize it myself, or to at least fool CF into treating it like its predecessor?
- Will all of my existing indexes work as-is (are?) with the new version?
- Has anyone out there on ServerFault done the upgrade? I'm especially interested in hearing about unforeseen or unexpected effects from the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded the default 1.4 install to 1.4.1 a couple of years ago. The only problem is that creating collections fails because the template folder arrangement is different. I worked around this by using a "wrapper" CFC to copy the template folder to the new collection location manually before running `<cfcollection action="create">`

I followed [these instructions](http://bytestopshere.wordpress.com/2010/09/14/lessons-learned-moving-from-verity-to-solr-part-4/), where you will also find useful information in the comments. The author has apparently upgraded to version 4.x without issue, but I'm not sure if the method was the same.